# Define unit vector in Python with s components

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I want to define a column vector v = (0, 0, …, 0, 1) in Python. The vector is supposed to have s components (for an arbitrary s), so the first s-1 components are supposed to be 0 and the last component 1. How do I do it? Because s is arbitrary. Thank you for your help in advance!

As I said, I wanted do use np.array but s is arbitrary. so I do not know how to use the np.array thingie (since the amount of components is not clear yet)

Comment: your problem isn't very clear. what's the problem with doing something simple like `np.array([0] * (s-1) + [1])` when you have s?

Comment: Make a zeros array of the right size, and set the last element: `x = np.zeros(5,int); x[-1]=1;`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is one option:

```
s = 10

v = np.repeat([0, 1], [s-1, 1])
```

Output: `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])`

You can generalize to any number of values:

```
# one "1", zero "2", three "3", two "4"
np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 3, 2])
# array([1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```